# Isomorphism between quotient by torsion subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need to find two abelian groups $G, H$ that are not isomorphic, but such that torsion subgroup $G_T$ and $H_T$ are isomorphic and $G/G_T$ and $H/H_T$ are isomorphic?

I tried with something of the form
$$G=\mathbb{Z_{n}}\oplus\mathbb{Z^r}$$ 
$$H=\mathbb{Z_{m}}\oplus\mathbb{Z^r}$$ 
bu I don't get how starting from two non-isomorphic groups I can have the torsion subgroups isomorphic if also the quotients are... evidentely there's something important I'm missing.

Comment: You mean $\oplus$ not $\otimes$. Finitely generated $G$ won't work.

Comment: Edited, thank you. Ahhh are you saying I should start looking for something not finitely generated?

Comment: If $G_T$ and $H_T$ are direct summands, you have lost ...

Comment: Any abelian group for which the torsion subgroup is not a direct summand will work (since you can then take $H=G/T\oplus T$). There are plenty of examples of such, one being the direct product of $C_{p^n}$ for all positive $n$, where $C_x$ is the cyclic group of order $x$.